# eclipse quick switch editor text not visible

Tags: eclipse

I cannot see the names of the files in eclipse "quick switch editor" (CTRL+E).
I use the last eclipse "Eclipse Neon.1" on Linux (I had this problem also with Eclipse Luna).
It seems like the foreground of the text is white like the background and I cannot see the option to change this in the preferences.
Does anyone have a solution ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experienced the same problem after upgrading from FC23 to FC25. The problem seems to be, that the text is drawn using the foreground color for tooltips, while the background color is unrelated to tooltips.

I was able to fix the problem by customizing my ~/.gtkrc-2.0 in this way:

```
style "myspecialtooltip" {
  xthickness = 13
  ythickness = 13
  bg[NORMAL]   = "#eeeedd"
  fg[NORMAL]   = "#000000"
  bg[SELECTED] = "#eeeedd"
}
widget "gtk-tooltip*" style "myspecialtooltip"
```

This changes the tooltip style from bright text on dark background to dark text on bright background, which also fixes the problem with eclipse's selection of colors.